# How do I see which curve is selected in the graph editor when I select a key frame?

Tags: graph-editor

I have bunch of joints and armature modifiers selected in this complex rig and I'm trying to see which one of them is selected when I click on one of the points in their curve in the graph editor. How can I tell which of the hundred curves is selected in the list of names when I select one of the curves?

Answer (score 1):

You can activate only show selected which will only include the selected bones

[image]

Comment: I'm asking. Let's say I have 5 bones selected. I click one of the curves in the graph editor. How can I tell which bone I'm selecting the curve of?

Answer (score 0):

Reviving this: I wish there was just some title somewhere that said the action of the selected keyframe. The best method I've found is this:

1. Select the keyframe/curve you want in the Graph Editor.
2. Shift-H in the Graph Editor to hide all the other curves.
3. Scroll through the list of actions on the left for the ones that are still enabled.
   If there's hundreds of actions to scroll through you can filter them by trying some various searches at the top of the tab: for instance if you search for "scale", and your keyframes are still visible in the Graph editor, you know they belong to some scale action and will hopefully have fewer actions to scroll through.